# Redirect HTTPS traffic to Port 3000 via AWS Load Balancing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Hello I am trying to enable https traffic to my website using AWS Load Balancing but I am facing some problems.

My nodejs app is using port 3000 on domain name like example.com
I am using Load Balancer to redirect the traffic from http on port 80 to http port 3000 so that I can open the app. But whenever I try to access the app via https like this: https://www.example.com, the website is not accessible.

Here is an example of what I changed:
[image]

But as I said, using this configuration only http://www.example.com is working
but I want to work with https://www.example.com

Comment: Can you confirm your security group allows port 443?

Comment: yes my security group allows port 443

Answer (score 0):

you should change your https from https to http port 3000 for https and add 443 as inbound rule with ipv4 rule set to 0.0.0.0/0. Then it will work for 3000

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).